# react-leaflet rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-leaflet, zustand

I have a Map react component that renders react-leaflet MapContainer. But it is not being rendered properly. When I zoom in and out the page itself, then it is being rendered properly. If you had similar issues and you fixed, please let me know!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86v9H.png)

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Circle,
  MapContainer,
  Marker,
  Popup,
  TileLayer,
  useMap,
} from "react-leaflet";
import { useDistrictStore } from "../../../stores/DistrictStore";

function Map({ formik }: { formik: any }) {
  const { currentArea } = useDistrictStore();

  function LocationMarker() {
    const map = useMap();
    useEffect(() => {
      map.on("click", (e) => {
        formik.setFieldValue("longitude", e.latlng.lng.toFixed(8));
        formik.setFieldValue("latitude", e.latlng.lat.toFixed(8));
      });
    }, [currentArea]);

    return formik.values.latitude === null ||
      formik.values.longitude === null ? null : (
      <Marker  position={[formik.values.latitude, formik.values.longitude]}>
        <Popup>Current Location</Popup>
      </Marker>
    );
  }

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[40.377592848986026, 71.79206670858817]}
      zoom={11}
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
    >
      <TileLayer url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
      <LocationMarker />
      <Circle
        center={[formik.values.latitude || 0, formik.values.longitude || 0]}
        radius={formik.values.radius * 1000}
      />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

When I zoom in and out the page itself, then it is being rendered properly. If you had similar issues and you fixed, please let me know!